# Docusign API Email Resource File French Language

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Docusign SOAP API in Salesforce. I would like to have the emails sent by docusign to be in french. As instructed in the documentation, I have changed the Email Resource file from the branding page of my docusign console, but in vain. It worked for other resource files but not for the email resource. Below are the steps:

1. In my code, I have set the email notification of the recipient to french:

   recipient.EmailNotification = new DocusignAPI.RecipientEmailNotification();
   recipient.EmailNotification.Language = 'fr';
   envelope.Recipients.Recipient[0] = recipient;
2. Downloaded the master email resource and added the french tag:

   ...
           Recipient has Viewed ENGLISH
           ...
       
       
           Recipient has Viewed FRENCH
3. When I launched the in person signature, all the screens were in french, but the emails were in english.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: When you set EmailNotification options for the recipient that only applies to that one recipient.  The "Recipient has Viewed" emails are sent to the sending user - not the signer.  I'm not sure how to set the language for the sender's email notifications.

Comment: We are facing a similar issue. Were you able to get a solution for your issue? If so please could you share it out here?